# Prevent client from overloading server?

Tags: java, servlets, request

I have a Java servlet that's getting overloaded by client requests during peak hours.  Some clients span concurrent requests.  Sometimes the number of requests per second is just too great.

Should I implement application logic to restrict the number of request client can send per second?  Does this need to be done on the application level?

Comment: As long as all the requests are valid then I agree with Anon, throw more hardware at it (easiest) or optimize your java servlet.  If the requests are spam like then you can block them at a lower layer using something like iptables or an apache level block

Comment: His question is valid. There can always be more requests than the hardware can handle. A server needs a way to limit the requests and now bring down the system during excessive loads.

Comment: Where is the bottleneck ? Are the people consuming the most bandwidth your biggest customers ? in that case you would not want to slow them down. More information would be great if you want further help. Maybe you just need to optimize some queries to get everything flowing smoothly ?

Comment: good answers.  Will I have to increase maxThreads for the connectors in Tomcat's config for Tomcat to utilize the added cpus and rams?   should I run tomcat in server mode?

Comment: @user121196: It's been a while, and your acceptance rating is quite low.  Please do everyone a favor and either select an answer or give us more information so we can help you more.  You'll find you get more and better help with a higher acceptance rating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common ways of handling this are to turn away requests when the server is too busy, or handle each request slower.

Turning away requests is easy; just run a fixed number of instances.  The OS may or may not queue up a few connection requests, but in general the users will simply fail to connect.  A more graceful way of doing it is to have the service return an error code indicating the client should try again later.

Handling requests slower is a bit more work, because it requires separating the servlet handling the requests from the class doing the work in a different thread.  You can have a larger number of servlets than worker bees.  When a request comes in it accepts it, waits for a worker bee, grabs it and uses it, frees it, then returns the results.

The two can communicate through one of the classes in [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/), like [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) or [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  If you want to get really fancy, you can use something like a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) to serve some customers before others.

Me, I would throw more hardware at it like Anon said ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some solid answers here. I think more hardware is the way to go. Having too many clients or traffic is *usually* a good problem to have.

However, if you absolutely must throttle clients, there are some options.

The most scalable solutions that I've seen revolve around a distributed caching system, like Memcached, and using integers to keep counts.

Figure out a rate at which your system can handle traffic. Either overall, or per client. Then put a count into memcached that represents that rate. Each time you get a request, decrement the value. Periodically increment the counter to allow more traffic through.

For example, if you can handle 10 requests/second, put a count of 50 in every 5 seconds, up to a maximum of 50. That way you aren't refilling it all the time, but you can also handle a bit of bursting limited to a window. You will need to experiment to find a good refresh rate. The key for this counter can either be a global key, or based on user id if you need to restrict that way.

The nice thing about this system is that it works across an entire cluster AND the mechanism that refills the counters need not be in one of your current servers. You can dedicate a separate process for it. The loaded servers only need to check it and decrement it.

All that being said, I'd investigate other options first. Throttling your customers is usually a good way to annoy them. Most probably NOT the best idea. :)

Comment: if you are successful in throttling a customer, you'll have  to explain the dead body.  But they won't be annoyed anymore :-)

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cust... cat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're not in a position to increase capacity (either via hardware or software), and you really just need to limit the externally-imposed load on your server.

Dealing with this from within your application should be avoided unless you have very special needs that are not met by the existing solutions out there, which operate at HTTP server level.  A lot of thought has gone into this problem, so it's worth looking at existing solutions rather than implementing one yourself.

If you're using Tomcat, you can configure the maximum number of simultaneous requests allowed via the maxThreads and acceptCount settings.  Read the introduction at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html for more info on these.

For more advanced controls (like per-user restrictions), if you're proxying through Apache, you can use a variety of modules to help deal with the situation.  A few modules to google for are limitipconn, mod_bw, and mod_cband. These are quite a bit harder to set up and understand than the basic controls that are probably offered by your appserver, so you may just want to stick with those.